# Edit method not working with foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am encountering an issue with my edit method for my event model, I noticed that the changes I am making are not saving to the database even though it seems to be working in the code (I have stepped through with breakpoints and all lines are executing), I have a feeling that perhaps the foreign keys are causing some issues but I am not sure.

This is the models I am using:

```
public class Event
{
    //ID
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int EventID { get; set; }

    //User ID Foregin Key
    public string OwnerID { get; set; }

    //Foreign Key for Club
    public int VenueID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("VenueID")]
    public virtual Venue Venue { get; set; }

    //Title
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a title")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string EventTitle { get; set; }

    //Date
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

    //Time
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a start time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}")]
    [Display(Name = "Time")]
    public DateTime EventTime { get; set; }

    //Description
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Give your event a brief description")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Details")]
    public string EventDescription { get; set; }

    //Event Category
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select a category from the list")]
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public Category EventCategory { get; set; }

    //Youtube Link     
    [Display(Name = "YouTube")]
    public string EventYouTube { get; set; }

    //SoundCloud Link
    [Display(Name = "SoundCloud")]
    public string EventSoundCloud { get; set; }

    //Facebook Link
    [Display(Name = "Facebook")]
    public string EventFacebook { get; set; }

    //Twitter Link
    [Display(Name = "Twitter")]
    public string EventTwitter { get; set; }

    //Instagram Link
    [Display(Name = "Instagram")]
    public string EventInstagram { get; set; }

    //Official Website Link
    [Display(Name = "Website")]
    [DataType(DataType.Url, ErrorMessage = "This is not a valid Url")]
    public string EventWebsite { get; set; }

    //Ticket Price
    [Display(Name = "Ticket Price")]
    public double? EventTicketPrice { get; set; }

    //Ticket Shop Link/ Location
    [Display(Name = "Ticket Vendor")]
    public string EventTicketStore { get; set; }

    //Image File 
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FileId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    public byte[] Content { get; set; }

    public FileType FileType { get; set; }

    public int EventID { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}

public class Venue
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int VenueID { get; set; }

    //Id for the owner of this venue
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }

    //List of events for this venue
    public List<Event> VenueEvents { get; set; }

    //Name
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a name")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string VenueName { get; set; }

    //Type
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Type")]
    public VenueType VenueType { get; set; }

    //Town
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select a town from the list provided")]
    [Display(Name = "Town")]
    public Town VenueTown { get; set; }

    //Address
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a street")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Street")]
    public string VenueAddress { get; set; }

    //Description
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Give your venue a brief description")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Details")]
    public string VenueDescription { get; set; }

    //Contact Email
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "This is not a valid email address")]
    public string VenueEmail { get; set; }

    //Contact Number
    [Display(Name = "Telephone")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber, ErrorMessage = "This is not a valid phone number")]
    public string VenuePhoneNumber { get; set; }

    //Image File 
    public virtual ICollection<VenueFile> VenueFiles { get; set; }
}
```

This is the controller methods:

```
// GET: Events/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Event @event = db.Events.Find(id);

    //Image
    @event = db.Events.Include(s => s.Files).SingleOrDefault(s => s.EventID == id);

    //Owner ID
    ViewBag.OID = @event.OwnerID;

    if (@event == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.VenueID = new SelectList(db.Venues, "VenueID", "OwnerId", @event.VenueID);


    return View(@event);
}

// POST: Events/Edit/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "EventID,OwnerID,VenueID,EventTitle,EventDate,EventTime,EventDescription,EventCategory,EventYouTube,EventSoundCloud,EventFacebook,EventTwitter,EventInstagram,EventWebsite,EventTicketPrice,EventTicketStore")] Event @event, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Event oldEvent = db.Events.Find(@event.EventID);

        @event.Venue = oldEvent.Venue;
        @event.VenueID = oldEvent.VenueID;
        @event.Files = oldEvent.Files;

        //Image
        if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            if (@event.Files.Any(f => f.FileType == FileType.EventImage))
            {
                db.Files.Remove(@event.Files.First(f => f.FileType == FileType.EventImage));
            }
            var img = new File
            {
                FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName),
                FileType = FileType.EventImage,
                ContentType = upload.ContentType
            };
            using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
            {
                img.Content = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
            }
            @event.Files = new List<File> { img };
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Events", @event.EventID);
    }
    ViewBag.VenueID = new SelectList(db.Venues, "VenueID", "OwnerId", @event.VenueID);
    return View(@event);
}
```

Note: When the db.SaveChanges is executed the model appears as follows -

```
EventCategory: Music
    EventDate: {05/11/2016 0:00:00}
    EventDescription: "desc edit"
    EventFacebook: null
    EventID: 40
    EventInstagram: null
    EventSoundCloud: "sc edit"
    EventTicketPrice: null
    EventTicketStore: null
    EventTime: {11/11/2016 22:00:00}
    EventTitle: "t edit"
    EventTwitter: null
    EventWebsite: null
    EventYouTube: "yt edit"
    Files: Count = 1
    OwnerID: "0f1c143f-323a-4e78-9489-89e451f7f30c"
    Venue: {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Venue_50A507AAD42F98D777DFCA0F94D77A0D914DD5D61DBECA66C53CA7450EAC1B1A}
    VenueID: 15
```

This is correctly reflects the changes I made in the edit view, but these changes do not seem to change in my db.

I also noticed that after this method is done it always jumps into the dispose method before going to the details method

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`db.Entry(@event).State = EntryState.Modified`
And then save changes

Comment: Be aware, that since you're using `Bind` to filter posted values, saving the posted event could have unintended side effects. Any value not included in the `Bind` will be cleared out once you save. You should never really save the posted instance, even if it's an entity class. Always pull the object fresh from the database and then map over any posted values on to *that* object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever do anything that would trigger Entity Framework to do an update. EF does change tracking and only issues something like an UPDATE if it has noticed that something in the context has changed or you've explicitly told it something has changed. You've done neither.

Traditionally, you would pull the object from the database as you've done here, and then *modify that object* with the posted values. Here you've only making changes to the object that was posted, which importantly, is not attached to your context. The object you pulled from the database and *is* in your context is never modified.